# Get just the text inner value of load() jquery with no tags no classes no ids no style

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#id").load("url #text");
```

returns

```
<h3 class="classname" style="background-color: transparent;">text</h3>
```

How do you get just the 'text' value and remove tags, classes, styles then
reformat it to

```
<span id="id" class="myclassname" style="background-color: red;">text</span>
```

Comment: A simple net search would have given you the jQuery `text()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you data only than you should use, [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), and then inside your call back you can easily set that data to your span element.

```
$.get( "url #text", function( data ) {
     // do something with data.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var span = $('<span id="id" class="myclassname" style="background-color: red;">text</span>');
span.text($($("#id").load("url #text")).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

```js
function replaceTag(oldTag, newTag) {
  $(oldTag).each(function(){
    var newElem = $(newTag, {html: $(this).html()});
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
      newElem.attr(this.name, this.value);
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(newElem);
  });
}

replaceTag('h3', '<span></span>');
$('span').attr('id','id');
$('span').css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="classname" style="background-color: transparent;">text</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to us `DOMParser` (which is useful even when the obtained result and desired output are more complex, because it turns the string into document on which you can perform all the queries you can perform on the real DOM) and parse the obtained string like this.

```js
const res = `<h3 class="classname" style="background-color: transparent;">text</h3>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(res, "text/html");
const text = doc.querySelector('h3').textContent;

document.querySelector('#id').innerHTML =
  `<span id="id" class="myclassname" style="background-color: red;">${text}</span>`;
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```